# Spark 2.2: does Spark SQL uses in-memory results of previously executed queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, in-memory

I have a Hive database and all tables from my examples are Hive tables in Parquet format.

Suppose **these are the first two** Spark SQL queries of my application (schema is simplified for the sake of the question):

```
1) val df1 = spark.sql("select * from T1 where T1.col1 = 'a'")
2) val df2 = spark.sql("select * from T1 where T1.col2 = 'b'")
```

When I execute an action I get different times depending on the order:

```
df1.count()
Time taken: 18062 ms
df2.count()
Time taken: 7037 ms
```

(on another Spark application / shell)

```
df2.count()
Time taken: 20330 ms
df1.count()
Time taken: 4131 ms
```

One way I am trying to explain this is that the second dataframe can take advantage of in-memory information left by the previous execution, because **both dataframes access the same table**.

However, the other day I tried something similar to this on **two different tables, T1 and T2**:

```
1) val df3 = spark.sql("select * from T1 where T1.col1 = 'c'")
2) val df4 = spark.sql("select * from T2 where T2.col1 = 'd'")
```

and got:

```
df3.count()
Time taken: 18062 ms
df4.count()
Time taken: 712 ms
```

(on another Spark application / shell)

```
df4.count()
Time taken: 11447 ms
df3.count()
Time taken: 15042 ms
```

So it seems that the dataframe executed last always achieves a better execution time than if it was executed first.

1) How is this possible especially in the case where two different tables are accessed? How can I explain this?

2) If this is not due to in-memory reusage of data, is there a way of getting rid of the overhead of the first execution?

3) If I had to report the execution time, would it be more fair to report the time when executed first or second?

Comment: What sort of Hive tables? csv, parquet, ORC? text?

Comment: Hard to make any comment as we do not know what was happening on the system at the same time, load, etc. The df4, df3 have no bearing on each other.

Comment: Could you please load couple of other tables lets suppose 10 tables. Then see what will happen. I believe your system has sufficient memory so it is not going to remove preloaded dataset and it's  simply going to run the query. If there are multiple tables and If spark has to load data then either it has to spillover or it has to remove from memory because of memory constraint. In this way we can truly check what is happening.

Comment: And also depends on Hive properties, if you have enabled the hive stats column then it will populated count and some basic stat. Since spark is going to look hive metadata then it can return the precomputed stats.

Comment: @thebluephantom Hive tables are in Parquet-format. I don't understand what you mean with your second comment.

Comment: @PrateekPrateek my database has approx. 90 tables of different sizes and even redundant representations of the same data. However, this behaviour can be reproduced by picking any two tables. I am not sure how I can check whether Hive stats column is enabled or not, but I will search.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that all queries are the first thing and only thing I am executing. So my application consists of only a spark.sql("use database x"), the 2 spark SQL queries and the 2 counts. Nothing else.

Comment: df3 and df4 are mutually exclusive sources, they should not influence each other.